# JavaScript function with multiple statements not working properly

Tags: javascript

I am using this javascript function.

```
get_staff_name = function(id) {
if (typeof StaffUsers != "object") {
    return "";
} else {
    $.each(StaffUsers, function(staff_id, name){
        if ( Number(staff_id)==Number(id) ) {
            return name;
        }
    });
}

return "NULL"; }
```

Every time it returns NULL.. I think after executing loop. JavaScript compiler goes to next statement and returns NULL,, I want if, if statement in loop true then return name and do not return NULL. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you paste your StaffUsers Object so i give you proper way to find name

Comment: I am not using ajax request in this function.

Comment: StaffUsers is something like this. StaffUsers = {"1":"user1","2":"user2"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
var StaffUsers = {"1":"user1","2":"user2"};
get_staff_name = function(id) {
  if (typeof StaffUsers === "object") {
    if(StaffUsers.hasOwnProperty(id)){
      return StaffUsers[id];
    }
  }
}
console.log(get_staff_name(1))
```

Comment: You'r right,, Your codes work... Thank you very much.

Comment: Your wel come:)

Answer (score 0):

The return here is the problem:

```
$.each(StaffUsers, function(staff_id, name){
    if ( Number(staff_id)==Number(id) ) {
        return name;
    }
});
```

it is returning for the $.each callback function and not your get_staff_name function. You need to do use a normal js loop, callback or something..

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
return name;
```

doesn't return from this function:

```
function(id) {
```

It returns from *this* one:

```
function(staff_id, name){
```

If you need to return from within the "loop" then I imagine a simple approach would be to use just a normal loop instead of `$.each()`.  Something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < StaffUsers.length; i++) {
    if (Number(i) == Number(id)) {
        return StaffUsers[i];
    }
};
```

Comment: @ShakeelAhmed: Perhaps your assumptions are incorrect and the `if` block never evaluates to `true`?  When you step through the code in your browser's debugger, is this `return` statement ever reached at all?  What are the values of the variable when you expect it to be reached?